# Issue with ethers.js v6 event handling in MetaMask

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethers.js

I'm encountering an issue with event handling in my DApp when using ethers.js v6 with MetaMask. Here's the situation:

- I've successfully deployed my contract on the Mumbai testnet using Hardhat.
- I'm using ethers.js v6 to connect to MetaMask (window.ethereum).
- Events emitted by the contract aren't being received when subscribing with `contract.on("EventName", callback)`.
- Interestingly, when I switch to an RPC provider like Alchemy on the same network, events are received without any issue.
- I also tested my code (below) by listening to the DAI token Transfer event and it works with Web3Provider and MetaMask.

I suspect there might be a compatibility issue or configuration step, or something that I'm not aware of about receiving events specific to MetaMask causing this discrepancy. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

// Assuming MetaMask is installed and injected as window.ethereum
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const contractAddress = "YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS";
const abi = [...]; // Your contract ABI definition
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);

// Subscribe to contract events
contract.on("eventName", (data) => {
  console.log("Event received:", data);
});
```

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with ethers.js v6 and MetaMask? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue or any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go with the addListener method like this.

```js
contract.addListener("eventName", (data) => {
  console.log("Event received:", data);
});
```